# can't access @OneToOne mapped entity

Tags: templates, scala, playframework-2.0, ebean

My data model:

```
public class Tour extends Model {    
    @Id
    public Integer id;

    @ManyToOne
    public Sport sport;

    @OneToOne(mappedBy="genericTour")
    FootballTour footballTour;

    @OneToOne(mappedBy="genericTour")
    TennisTour tennisTour;

    public static Finder<Integer, Tour> find(){
        return new Finder<Integer,Tour>(Integer.class,Tour.class);
    }
}

public class FootballTour extends Model {

    @Id
    public Integer id;

    @OneToOne
    Tour genericTour;

    public static Finder<Integer, FootballTour> find(){
        return new Finder<Integer,FootballTour>(Integer.class,FootballTour.class);
    }

}
```

My action(just to show that I'm fetching "footballTour"):

```
  public static Result getToursBySportTag(String sportTag){

      Query query = Tour.find().fetch("sport").fetch("footballTour");
      List<Tour> finedTours =  query.where().eq("tag", sportTag).findList();

      return ok(tours.render(finedTours));

  }
```

In scala template I want to acess footballTour field of Tour:

```
@(tours: List[Tour])
@main("Football tours") {
<h1>Football tours List</h1>
<dl>
@for(tour <- tours) {
<dt>
<a href="@routes.Application.tour(tour.id)">
@tour.footballTour.id
</a>
</dt>
}
</dl>
}
```

And have error at compilation time:

> [error] one error found [error]
>   {file:/C:/Users/pc/prog/}prog/compile:compile: C ompilation failed
>   [info] Compiling 1 Scala source to C:\Users\pc\prog\target\scala-2.
>   9.1\classes... [error] C:\Users\pc\prog\target\scala-2.9.1\src_managed\main\views\
>   html\tours.template.scala:37: **variable footballTour in class Tour
>   cannot be acce ssed in models.Tour** [error]
>   """),*display*(Seq[Any](/%2a8.2%2a/tour/%2a8.6%2a/.name)),format.raw/*8.11*/("""
>    - """),*display*(Seq[Any](/%2a8.15%2a/tour/%2a8.19%2a/.footballTour.id)),format.raw/*8.
>   35*/(""" [error]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The field `genericTour` of the `FootballTour` class should be public:

```
public class FootballTour extends Model {

    @Id
    public Integer id;

    @OneToOne
    public Tour genericTour;  // <<<<< Here !!

    public static Finder<Integer, FootballTour> find(){
        return new Finder<Integer,FootballTour>(Integer.class,FootballTour.class);
    }

}
```

In java, by default, in not specified, the fields are private.

Comment: The field can be labelled protected too.